# I'm passing data from UITableViewController to UIViewController through protocols and instead of int value I'm getting nil. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two UITableViewController, the first one:

```
protocol FetchUserProfileData {
    func getNumberOfRequests()
}

class ListEvents: UITableViewController{
    var fetchInfo:FetchUserProfileData?

    func getNumberOfRequests() -> Int{
        return 12
    }
```

and the UIViewController:

```
class UserProfileDetails:UIViewController, FetchUserProfileData {

var listEvents: UserListEvents?

func getNumberOfRequests(){

    }

override func viewDidLoad(){
listEvents?.fetchInfo = self
print(listEvents?.getNumberOfRequests())
```

and this line: `print(listEvents?.getNumberOfRequests())` gives me a `nil` value instead of `12`... What's wrong here?

---- edit
Ok, now I see that listEvents is empty... So my question is how can I pass that data from ListEvents to UserProfileDetails?

Comment: Please elaborate on how you intend to pass data from one controller to another using a protocol. As far as I know, protocols can't be used to exchange data.  A protocol only defines a set of functions that a class that implements that protocol must have.

Comment: hm I just thought that when I do it like I tried - with returning an int value with a function then I will have a direct access to that value... Can you tell me how to pass it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In this code, `listEvents` is probably nil.

But, the way you use the protocol looks odd to me.  I would expect:

1. `getNumberOfRequests` in the protocol to return Int
2. `ListEvents` should be implementing the protocol, not `UserProfileDetails`
3. The empty `getNumberOfRequests()` in `UserProfileDetails` should be deleted

Comment: Ok, speaking about point no.2 - I'm confused, because I want to pass the data from ListEvents to UserProfileDetails, not the other way around, so I thought I'm doing that right? Can you show me some simple example, like a block schema or something of how could I pass that data then?

Answer (score 0):

You did not set `listEvents`. When you are using story boards then you should set the `fetchInfo` not earlier than in (overwriting) `prepareForSegue`. Google for examples, the web is full of them. When you segue programmatically then you can set the property not before you actually instanticated the new view controller. You are better of using `listEvents!.fetchInfo = self` because in that case you'll get an exception when listEvents is nil.

Answer (score 0):

I made some change your code and this will pass data from ListEvents to UserProfileDetails.

```
  protocol FetchUserProfileDelegate {
  func getNumberOfRequests()->Int
}

class ListEvents: UITableViewController,FetchUserProfileDelegate{
  var userProfile: UserProfileDetails?
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    userProfile = UserProfileDetails()
    userProfile?.delegate = self
  }
  // MARK: FetchUserProfileDelegate
  func getNumberOfRequests() -> Int{
    return 12 // return as your target Int
  }
}

class UserProfileDetails:UIViewController {

   var delegate:FetchUserProfileDelegate?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let _ = delegate{
      let resultInt = delegate?.getNumberOfRequests() // get the Int form ListEvents
      print(resultInt)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this exact way but somehow I'm not entering the `if let _ = delegate{...` block, do you know how could I fix it?

Comment: I didn't mention it in the original question and I'm not sure whether it changes the concept of the solution, but those two panels (`UITableViewController` and `UIViewController`) are both embedded in two containers stored on another `UIViewController` - can it be the reason why your current solution doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of moving data from one controller to another is very common. Most of the time this is done using a segue. A controller can have a function called prepareForSegue. This function gets called before the transition happens. Inside the prepareForSegue function, the system gives you destination controller object. You take that object and set your data in it. When the transition happens, and your destination controller comes up, it already has the data you want to give to it.

Use Xcode and make a new project. Choose "Master-Detail Application".  This will generate the code for you and it is a good example of how to pass data between controllers.